# Nativescript Development For Windows Phone

Tags: nativescript

I'd like to ask tutorial about Nativescript for Windows Phone?
I already search on google but there is no tutorial about developing windows phone app using native script.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nativescript for Windows Phone is not released yet. As far as I remember, the preview version should be available in May 2015.

Comment: Thank you, you're right man. 

i search some limitation in current version of nativescript. http://docs.telerik.com/platform/appbuilder/nativescript/getting-started-ns/limitations